# show groups pf X values with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a graph with x=(1-600), and y=(1-100).
I would like to group my x values, and show the groups in the plot.
for example: 
x between 1 and 10 = A;
x between 11 and 30= B;
plot with A and B (instead of all X values).

Thank You in advance for your time!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Do you just want to constrain the graph on the X axis?
Or do you want to split the input data into two arrays and plot on one graph?

Comment: just contrain the graph on the X axis, so a graph that has on the X axes A and B

Answer (score 0):

If you just want just contrain the graph on the X axis, this might help you:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

n = 600
x = range(n)
y = [100 * random.random() for i in range(n)]

a = 10
b = 30

plt.xlim(a, b) 
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Without limits:

[image]

With limits:

[image]